# React Native IOS, library linking is not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-linking

I am working on react native application, I have updated react native version of my app. After installing packages and updating pods, I run command to link all libraries::

> react-native link

But it doesn't work then I have tried manual linking, now there is no library file inside target -> Build Phases -> Link Binary With Libraries
If I am trying to add ".a" file it gives me an error.
I am quite surprised, my project still running properly on the simulator without linking to libraries.
You can check this image, I am using react-native-navigation. It's running properly without linking.
[image]

After adding the library I am getting "Dependency Analysis Error"

> Unable to run command 'Libtool libReactNativeNavigation.a' - this
>   target might include its own product.

Now my project is running properly but there is no library inside "Link Binary With Libraries" section.

The environment I am using as follows::

1. react-native : 0.59.9
2. xCode: 10.1
3. react: 16.8.6

Please suggest to me what I am doing wrong here. Or is this right methodology?

Comment: Fyi, your project is probably running from the build cache, if you clean all build intermediates it's likely to break so don't be disillusioned into thinking that there is no problem.

Comment: @Nit what should I do to clean build cache??

Comment: and why I am not able to add library here?? What is the problem here

Comment: @Nit I have cleared all cache but still there is the same issue.